# ajax data xml string always empty

Tags: jquery, ajax, xml

I have this problem when I send xml data string to the server side, the server side always sees an empty string :

```
$(document).on('click','#metadataListTable .delete', function () {  /
            var ans = confirm("Do you want to delete Metadata?");
            if(ans==true){
             var nRow = $(this).parents('tr')[0];
             var data = oTable.row( $(this).parents('tr') ).data();
             alert( data[10] +" ========= "+ data[11] );
             oTable.row( $(this).parents('tr')).remove().draw();
        $.ajax({
            url: "deleteMetadata.do",
            data: "id=" + nRow.id + "&flag=" + "T" + "&ifData=" + data[10] + "&env=" + data[11],
            success: function(response) {
               // alert(response.message);
               toastr.success(response.message);

            }
        })            
    }
});
```

The columns where I got the data :

```
<td class="idata">&lt;Interface environment=&quot;QA&quot; from=&quot;rm&quot; name=&quot;8zxjckeq&quot; to=&quot;rm&quot; version=&quot;4.0&quot;&gt;\r&lt;HTTPS/&gt;\r&lt;/Interface&gt;</td>
<tdclass="edata">QA</td>
```

data[10] =" <Interface environment="QA" from="rm" name="8zxjckeq" to="rm" version="4.0">\r<HTTPS/>\r</Interface> "

and data[11] ="QA"

when I go to the server side to read the value of  ifData :

```
String ifaceData = request.getParameter("ifData");
```

It is always empty.

Thanks, your help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of making the query string in the *data* param, do it as a JSON object:

```
data: "id=" + nRow.id + "&flag=" + "T" + "&ifData=" + data[10] + "&env=" + data[11],
```

to

```
data: {
    id: nRow.id,
    flag: 'T',
    ifData: data[10],
    env: data[11]
}
```